# how do I return a value from my async function?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

So I have an async funtion:

```
Future decodeToken() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var token = await prefs.getString('token');
  final Map<String, dynamic> payload = json.decode(
    ascii.decode(
      base64.decode(base64.normalize(token.split(".")[1])),
    ),
  );
  return payload;
}
```

and when I try do do:

```
var payload = await decodeToken();
```

it throws an error saying "The await expression can only be used in an async function."

I tried taking out the "await" and print the payload variable but obviously it prints "Instance of Future"

if I do:

```
decodeToken().then((value)=>print(value))
```

it prints the value correctly, but I want to use it in a variable, how do I return the vvalue of an async function?

Comment: Please do not edit answers into the question. If you have an answer, post an answer to your own question. Since, your question is closed as a duplicate, add an answer to the duplicate if you believe it will help future users.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is saying you can only use `await` in a method that is marked as `async`, so you are calling an asynchronous method from a synchronous one and Dart doesn't like that.

You have several options:

1. Use the `Future...then` pattern:

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> payload;
decodeToken().then((data) {
  payload = data;
});
```

2. Make the surrounding method `async`:

```dart
void foo() async {
  var payload = await decodeToken();
}
```

3. Use a `FutureBuilder` (if you need your future's data in the build method):

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: decodeToken(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        // Future hasn't completed yet, display something in the meantime
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
      // Future has completed, get data
      var payload = snapshot.data;
      ...
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Define the return type as `Future<Map<String, dynamic>>`

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> decodeToken() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var token = await prefs.getString('token');
  final Map<String, dynamic> payload = json.decode(
    ascii.decode(
      base64.decode(base64.normalize(token.split(".")[1])),
    ),
  );
  return payload;
}
```